# My VS Code opens up automatically after installing Deepin Desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

So I've **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** [installed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5MhydijWmc&t=1111s) on my Windows as a *Virtual OS* through VirtualBox. A few days back I heard about the release of [Deepin 20 Beta](https://www.deepin.org/en/2020/04/15/deepin-20-beta/#:%7E:text=deepin%20is%20a%20Linux%20distribution,a%20brand%20new%20interactive%20experience.).

And I got obsessed with its

## Desktop Interface

[image: Desktop Interface].

So I searched for ways to get that desktop interface on my Ubuntu which led to [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/07/install-deepin-desktop-ubuntu-20-04-lts/).

After following those steps and **rebooting** my virtual OS, the first thing I did was open the terminal and:

```
prince@mylaptop:~$cd Desktop
prince@mylaptop:~$code .
```

Yeah, that's right. I opened my VS Code and then I did my usual coding, etc.

But from then on whenever I open my Virtual Machine, VS Code gets opened automatically and it has been really frustrating.

It is almost like the feeling you get when you get adds at the beginning the moment you try to watch a video on youtube.

Is there any way to stop it? I've searched for it on the internet but found nothing related to this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a VirtualBox expert, but it does offer an option to keep the machine state on shutdown. Isn't that the problem?

If you do not close the Visual Code window and shut down your machine by choosing "*Save the machine state*", VS Code will automatically restart at startup.

See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB2KP.png

The "*Power off the machine*" option could be the solution.

Comment: Your answer makes sense but I did not  choose "*Save the machine state*" to shut down my machine and still VS Code fire's up automatically...